# Weakref-ing an item from one dict in a subdict of another in python

Tags: python, dictionary, weak-references

This is a bit of a complicated question setup but I'll explain it best I can. I'm in a situation where I have two dictionaries, `dict1` and `dict2`. `dict1` contains every item in both dictionaries, but it keeps the actual objects (and not a reference to the objects). Another important factor is that `dict1` stores all the items in one dictionary; itself.

`dict2` however is partitioned up into subdicts, each subdict containing one or more items from `dict1` such that all the objects in `dict1` are also in the intersection of the subdicts of `dict2` and there are no duplicates. Now the problem is that I want to make weak references to the items in the `dict2`'s subdicts such that when the item is deleted from the `dict1`, so is it's reference in the subdict of `dict2`.

For example:

```
>>> import weakref
>>> dict1 = {}
>>> dict2 = {'subdict': {}}
>>> class Object: pass

>>> a = Object()
>>> a_ref = weakref.ref(a)
>>> dict1['a'] = a
>>> dict2['subdict']['a'] = a_ref
>>> del dict1['a']
>>> assert not dict2['subdict']['a']() # raises an assertion error
```

How might I go about doing this? Is it even possible with weakrefs? Am I misinterpreting the purpose of weakrefs?

Comment: "it keeps the actual objects (and not a reference to the objects)". In python everything is a reference. No data structure "keeps the actual objects". You can treat your data structure as the "main" one, holding the "main" references, and others holding additional references, but that's just the semantics you associate to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make all of the subdictionaries [`WeakValueDictionary`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary)s? Then, when the only strong reference in `dict1` is removed, the weakref in the `WeakValueDictionary` will cause that entry to be deleted automatically.

Example:

```
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> import weakref
>>> d1 = {}
>>> d2 = {'sub': weakref.WeakValueDictionary()}
>>> d1['a'] = A()
>>> d2['sub']['a'] = d1['a']
>>> del d1['a']
>>> d2['sub']['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'a'
```

Be sure that during your testing you don't accidentally have a local or global variable bound to your object (e.g. in your example, `a` is still a local name bound to the `Object()` instance, which will keep it alive). You can `del` names (e.g. `del a`) to ensure they are cleared.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to work. The setup I was using was exactly how you described as well. However I could always be doing something wrong, would you mind showing some code to illustrate your point?

Comment: Ahh, that was my problem, not deleting the local name bound to the object. Thanks for explaining!